# How does the bone constraint follow path work

Tags: path

I am not very skilled at blender, but anyways, I was working on a project with follow path and realised that across the whole animation in follow path the location of the object does not change but it somehow still moves. I don't understand why this is and I need to know the location of the object because i'm animating wheels from the location of the object which is a car.

Comment: Please show some screensots of what's happening and maybe share your file

Comment: May be the root bone follows the path not the object.

Comment: Ok i'll upload my file, sorry about that. The car is already animated to the path but i can't see what location changes. Also I'm using a car rigging system called rigacar. Thanks. The link is to google drive is https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zpNi9kR-ZIJKyqH0cLG6SvEyMO6I6uD-

Comment: I found that the origin of the rig stays at the 0,0,0 coordinate but the the mesh and rig move as if separate from the origin which is why the coordinates of the rig doesn't change, but i don't know why this happens and i need the origin to follow along as well.